# CompletableFuture.runAsync not finishing execution

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, javafx, completable-future

I'm attempting to use CompletableFuture to write a large number of pixels on a JavaFX canvas, and my method does not seem to be completing its task despite no exceptions being thrown.

I'm new to asynchronous programming and am not sure where I should begin, but I thought this might work from what info I've gathered.

I'm attempting to use:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                mandelbrot.increaseScale();
                drawMandelbrot();
            });
```

to call:

```
private void drawMandelbrot() {
    //RENDER

    gc.clearRect(0,0,UISpecs.CANVAS_SIZE.getValue(),UISpecs.CANVAS_SIZE.getValue()); // clears canvas of any previously set pixels
    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK); // set canvas background to be black
    gc.fillRect(0,0,UISpecs.CANVAS_SIZE.getValue(),UISpecs.CANVAS_SIZE.getValue()); // set canvas background

    for(double a = -2; a <= 2; a+=.001) {
        for(double b = -2; b <= 2; b+=.001) {
            c = new Complex(a,b);
            col = pickColor(doIterations(c));
            p.setColor(mandelbrot.getX(a), mandelbrot.getY(b), col);
        }
    }
} // drawMandelbrot()
```

My complex(a,b) and pickColor(i) methods are quite trivial, both do very small and simple operations. So I believe my nested loops are what is causing my trouble.

Any guidance or input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming `gc` is a `GraphicsContext` assigned to a `Canvas` that is currently part of the scene graph (displayed in any stage/window), your code will throw an exception for trying to modify the scene graph from a thread other than the JavaFX thread. This exception will have been caught by the `CompletableFuture`, and you should be able to see it using the `get` method.

Comment: I am assuming your application doesn't exits before the computation is complete. Despite your statement that no exceptions are being thrown I don't see any checks in your code to check them, pls add `CompletableFuture.runAsync().exceptionally()` to check for exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

`CompletableFuture` is an implementation of the `Future` interface
and you want your pixels to be rendered onto the canvas asynchronously
but you are not waiting for the future to complete its computation ,

```
CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture =CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                mandelbrot.increaseScale();
                drawMandelbrot();
            });
completableFuture.get();
```

The documentation for CompletableFuture.get() puts it clearly :
Waits for the async computation to finish and then returns